# Can two packets propagate on the same communication link?

Tags: networking

Can two packets, say from host A, propagate on the same communication link while the first one is still on its way to the next point, say host B?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the same physical link, no. The source needs to finish sending a packet before it can start a new one. Packets are atomic and cannot overlap.

Physically, with the limited propagation speed of a signal, the destination may still be receiving the previous packet while the source has already started transmitting the next one. With a 10 Gbit/s link and a propagation speed of 200,000 km/s, a single bit is just 2 cm "long". For a minimum sized Ethernet frame that's just 13.5 m, so a longer cable could actually hold one or more entire frames. [*figures corrected*]

On a logical link, consisting of multiple physical links, it is normal for the source to send many packets while the destination is still receiving previous packets. In the TCP transport-layer protocol, the *window size* defines the amount of data that can be "in flight".

Comment: Even a single bit of a packet has to get the destination before the source can send the next one on the same physical link?

Comment: @jeysmith No. Data is sent serialized in packets or frames. When a frame is finished a new one can be started. Maybe my edit to the answer makes this clearer.

Comment: What I want to figure out is what exactly happens at a physical layer (on the cable). As a bit is an electrical signal, I presume that a packet is a "bunch" of electrical signals, so, as far as I understood now, a few electrical signals can travel on the same cable simultaneously before the first one gets its destination. To make it simple, say computer A linked to computer B via one cable. Did I get it right?.

Comment: Data is also transmitted on optical fiber, and the "bits" can also be multi-bit symbols, but yes, a packet or a frame is a bunch of those line symbols. It depends what you mean with "simulateously" - you can only feed one packet/frame at a time into a cable but generally, multiple, sequential frames can be travelling on a single cable in a given moment; see the italicized paragraph.

Comment: I think I've understood now. Thanks

Comment: @jeysmith You should accept the answer if it helped you, so that it doesn't keep popping up.

Comment: @Cown to accept it? How?

Comment: @jeysmith Just click on the check mark next to the answer. ;-)